# VisualBasic 2010 Syntax Refresher

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, syntax

With Parallels and WinXP installed, I thought I'd put VisualStudio back on my computer and tinker around a bit, but it's been a while and I'm a bit rusty with it.  Can someone refer me to a quick and easy guide to VBasic syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a loook at these

[Visual Basic .NET Syntax Reference Primer](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=429)

and

[VB.NET Basics Quick Reference Sheet (Cheat Sheet)](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic31908.htm)

Comment: Spot on the mark, and with plenty of bonus material.  Thanks a lot!